# Ubuntu DNS issues

Tags: ubuntu, dns

Ubuntu 11.10

DNS works fine with `nslookup` and `dig`

```
sr@sr-ThinkPad-R52:~$ nslookup ocelot.rmg.local
Server:     192.168.0.100
Address:    192.168.0.100#53

Name:   ocelot.rmg.local
Address: 192.168.0.100

sr@sr-ThinkPad-R52:~$ dig ocelot.rmg.local

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> ocelot.rmg.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 7831
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ocelot.rmg.local.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ocelot.rmg.local.   10800   IN  A   192.168.0.100

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ocelot.rmg.local.   10800   IN  NS  ocelot.rmg.local.

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.100#53(192.168.0.100)
;; WHEN: Sun Jan 15 17:14:41 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 64
```

And `curl` can connect to hosts directly

```
sr@sr-ThinkPad-R52:~$ curl -I http://192.168.0.100/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 15 Jan 2012 17:15:45 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.11 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8k PHP/5.3.0
Last-Modified: Sat, 25 Jul 2009 05:17:17 GMT
ETag: "31bdb-13e6-46f80d59a5140"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 5094
Cache-Control: max-age=60
Expires: Sun, 15 Jan 2012 17:16:45 GMT
MS-Author-Via: DAV
X-Frame-Options: SameOrigin
Content-Type: text/html
```

but nothing (Firefox, Curl etc.) will let me connect to hosts via DNS

```
sr@sr-ThinkPad-R52:~$ curl -I http://ocelot.rmg.local/
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'ocelot.rmg.local'
sr@sr-ThinkPad-R52:~$ curl -I http://google.co.uk/
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'google.co.uk'
```

So `nslookup` and `dig` resolve domains correctly but nothing else will. First DNS works fine everywhere else on the network.

```
sr@sr-ThinkPad-R52:~$ sudo cat /etc/resolv.conf 
[sudo] password for sr: 
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.0.100
sr@sr-ThinkPad-R52:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:41:15:f5:a9  
          inet addr:192.168.0.51  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::216:41ff:fe15:f5a9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:928 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:550 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:97057 (97.0 KB)  TX bytes:74362 (74.3 KB)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

As requested

```
sr@sr-ThinkPad-R52:~$ dig ipv6.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> ipv6.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 3009
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ipv6.google.com.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ipv6.google.com.    604308  IN  CNAME   ipv6.l.google.com.

;; Query time: 311 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.100#53(192.168.0.100)
;; WHEN: Mon Jan 16 16:21:21 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 54

sr@sr-ThinkPad-R52:~$ dig ipv6.l.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> ipv6.l.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 57474
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ipv6.l.google.com.     IN  A

;; Query time: 124 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.100#53(192.168.0.100)
;; WHEN: Mon Jan 16 16:22:00 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 35
```

Not on an IPV6 network so `curl` wouldn't work for that anyway

Comment: What do nslookup and dig give you for a host outside the local domain? Perhaps name server 192.168.0.100 is not resolving?

Comment: **What permissions does `/etc/resolv.conf` have? (They must be 0644 - i.e. world-readable.)** What name resolution methods do you have configured in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, the `hosts` line? (It must contain `dns` in the list.) Does `getent -s dns hosts google.com` work?

Comment: @grawity `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 55 2012-01-15 17:08 /etc/resolv.conf`, nsswitch: `files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4`, `getent` works correctly

Comment: @chakram88 It's in the original question, I tried `curl`ing google.com. And since .0.100 is the only DNS server on the network how else would it resolve external domains?

Comment: @sam: it is not in the original question. You did a curl for google, I asked what nslookup and dig return for hosts outside the local domain. You show us `nslookup <localdomain>` and `dig <localdomain>` and then `curl <localdomain>` and `curl google.com`.

Comment: @chakram88 DNS lookups for outside domains work fine (would update with actual output but I'm not on the network). Sorry I thought I'd put it in.

Comment: Now try `AAAA` queries and show people the results in your question.

Comment: Now try `AAAA` queries **properly**.  You weren't asked for `A` queries against a different domain name.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try any other software? Like ping, telnet, ssh?

For example, can you give the output of

```
strace ping google.co.uk
```